# Can't Install Apache ant on Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: android, macos, apache, ant

I followed these guides but with no result:

The First Guide:

1. Download ant from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
2. move the extracted folder to home
3. open terminal and type: open -e .bash_profile
4. then I added to my path and the path as follow:

> export
>   PATH=$PATH:/Users/ayman/adt/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/ayman/adt/sdk/tools:/Users/ayman/ant/bin

the Second Guide:

1. Download ant from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
2. move the extracted folder to home
3. open terminal and type: nano $HOME/.profile
4. append these: export PATH=$PATH:/Users/ayman/ant/bin
   export ANT_HOME=/Users/ayman/ant/bin
5. source $HOME/.profile

But after both when I try to run in terminal : `ant -version` , it gives me `command not found`

Answer (score 0):

The appended path needs to be reloaded in your bash profile. It looks like you have not quit terminal and restarted your bash session. Once bash restarts and your .profile is reloaded, bash should find ant.

/edit:

The second guide must be correct as the bash profile loaded under 10.10 is ~/.profile. Make sure correct path is declared in that file, save it and restart you bash.

Comment: does ~/ant exist? make sure the correct path exists in your ~/.profile - ignore .bash_profile, that's not relevant to 10.10 bash.

Comment: this is the path in .profile and .bash_profile :

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/ayman/adt/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/ayman/adt/sdk/tools:/Users/ayman/ant/bin